# completion = autocomplete ≠ auto-complete

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [autocomplete](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete) is being used for at least two things:

- The general concept of completion, for which [completion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completion) is also used
- The [`auto-complete` package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/auto-complete.el)

How can we disambiguate them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it is technically possible to have both [autocomplete](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete) and [auto-complete](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-complete) (this requires moderator intervention to create the second tag), this is very much prone to confusion, so I don't advocate it.

Given that Emacs calls the concept “Completion”, I favor using [completion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completion) for the general concept.

A decent unambiguous tag name for the auto-complete package would be [auto-complete.el](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-complete.el). Malabarba proposed [auto-complete-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-complete-mode), we're going for that instead.

I propose to retag all questions currently tagged [autocomplete](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete) to [completion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completion) or [auto-complete-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-complete-mode) as appropriate.

There's a risk that [autocomplete](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete) will turn back up, because outside Emacs, the prefix “auto” is used very often. If it does, we can add a synonym [autocomplete](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete) → [completion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completion), or we can blacklist the tag and show a disambiguation message like “for the general concept, use [completion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completion); for the auto-complete package, use [auto-complete-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-complete-mode)”.

Comment: I'd slightly prefer auto-complete-mode instead of auto-complete.el, but otherwise agree completely. :)

Comment: Agreed on `auto-complete-mode`.  Searching existing tags and you have several `*-mode` and currently no `*.el` (or `*-el`).  I would vote for blacklist over synonym simply to avoid people being redirected to `completion` when they did mean `auto-complete-mode` and didn't read far enough.

Comment: I don't feel strongly about it, but I think that I think (!) that `autocomplete.el` is clearer than `auto-complete-mode`. And the idea is general (if ever we need to apply it again). Consider `highlighting` (general) vs `highlight-mode` (hypothetical, specific to a library) vs [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el) (an actual library). Anyway, +1 for the "question".

Comment: For the moment, lets go with auto-complete-mode for the sake of consistency with every other tag out there. But this `mode` vs `.el` discussion is probably worth bringing to its own question. I must say @Drew's points are winning me over.

Comment: @Malabarba: Consistency is less important than clarity and non-ambiguity. Not that it's important in this case. But it is better to judge each tag wrt **its** possible interpretations than it is to respect a rule. And yes, the existence of a general rule does affect individual interpretations - and generally positively. That's the advantage of consistency: people know what to expect, and they guess accordingly. It is both the strength (when the rule guides us well) and the weakness (when the rule misleads us).

Comment: First, that would be `auto-complete.el`. And then, it's only one of the files comprising the `auto-complete` package. Second, I think `auto-complete-mode` is specific enough, and the package is referred by that name in many other places, e.g. in GitHub discussions.

Comment: @Dmitry: Agreed, for this case.  And the main point here is that we should avoid `auto-complete` and `autocomplete` as the tag, because that has a wider/different meaning.